# Implementing shortest path algorithm Java with list of edges

Tags: java

I am writing a method in Java to find the shortest path between two nodes in a graph.
The parameters are the following

- an array list of "edges": objects containing the index of the source node of the edge and the index of the destination node of the edge
- index1: the first index
- index2: the index I want to find the shortest path to.

I have written the following code:

```
    public static String shortestDistance(List<edge> edges, int index1, int index2) {
    String shortest = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
            edge e = edges.get(i);
            if (e.src == index1) {
                  //shortest path here
                shortest = shortest + e.src + ", ";

            }
        }
        return shortest;
}
```

My goal is to return a string containing a list of the shortest possible path. How do I begin to implement an algorithm to search for the shortest path between the two indexes?

Comment: You likely want to use a graph data structure first, and populate the graph edges with your edge list

Comment: @JimN this makes sense but I'm not sure how to go from a list of edges and an index of nodes to an actual graph data structure. Could you point me in the right direction on that?

Comment: It really depends on what you are most comfortable with. You could use an int[][] as an adjacency matrix. I prefer an adjacency list as a Map from integers to ArrayLists (initialized as Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adj = new HashMap<>();  ) But if you haven't learned about Java maps, then you can get away with an array of arrayLists, especially considering it seems your vertices are integers. But this also sort of assumes your n nodes are integers labeled 0 to n-1, while the Map version would allow vertices to be anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use Breadth First Search to find the shortest path from one node to another in a graph.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-breadth-first-search